# The public type PlayerQuitListener must be defined in its own file

Tags: java, minecraft

I am almost done with making a compass that tracks a player but Im getting this error "The public type PlayerQuitListener must be defined in its own file" so i made a new file called "PlayerQuitListener.java" but it is still not fixed? How would I fix this? Thank you!

[Main Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sl1g.png)

[How I tried to fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixyg7.png)

Comment: Or you could rename the file to have the same name as your class as it's supposed to be.

Comment: [Why can't I upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: If that comment was on mine, I don't know if it was i've never used this, then they are the same name.

Comment: So what's the problem? Your fix no longer exhibits this problem.

Comment: @Artourious I'm not sure what your last comment means, but in case mine was not clear, I meant that `PlayerQuitListener` should be in a file called `PlayerQuitListener.java`. Your attempted fix doesn't help because your original `PlayerQuitListener` is still in the wrong file. Just rename the file and delete the new (almost empty) one you created

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! Im sorry about my first comment I meant I was not sure if those comments were on my post.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the file in PlayerQuitListener.java and it should be fine,the problem is that the class name must match the file name, delete the empty file, rename CPCommand.java in PlayerQuitListener.java and it should work